# Where is clamav cron?

Tags: clamav

My clamav runs at the same time every day. But I can't for the life of me figure out where it's configured. Freshclam runs once in the crontab. Does that trigger clamscan to run? Is it just always on? Should it be? How can I set it to just run once at a given time?

Answer (score 0):

You must have the clamav-daemon installed and running. This would run clamscan once a day or whatever the default was in that version at install. You can configure some settings in clamd.conf.